# jquery select form, filter with chained find fails - returns empty result

Tags: jquery, serialization

I have a form with multiple input elements and need to serialize - convert to HTTP query string. That works fine. Then I wanted to get rid of one of the input values, so I used find to select all elements not equal to that one; that works fine. But then I tried to remove two inputs by chaining two finds together and it fails.

I know that disabling the unwanted input or removing the name attribute will also work, but those options are not sensible in my application.

I have a jsfiddle to demonstrate: http://jsfiddle.net/dr_glenn/H8ZwL/

Let me summarize here. There is a form like this:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name='aa' value='aa'>
<input type="text" name='bb' value='bb'>
<input type="text" name='cc' value='cc'>
</form>
```

jquery code like this:

```
query_args = $('#form').serialize();
alert( query_args );  // looks OK
query_args = $('#form').find('[name!="bb"]').serialize();
alert( query_args );  // Very good, 'bb' is gone
query_args = $('#form').find('[name!="bb"]').find('[name!="cc"]').serialize();
alert( query_args );  // FAIL! Nothing is displayed.
```

---

If I've just made some dumb noob mistake, please try to be nice!

Comment: After contemplating the answer, I did further searches and updated my fiddle. Now I understand that "[name!='cc'][name!='ee']" is a set intersection operation, whereas separating the two clauses with comma "[name!='cc'],[name!='ee']" is a set union. So the set union will give wrong result - all input elements will be returned. Since union and intersection are similar to OR and AND, I also tested the alternate clause ":not([name='cc'],[name='ee'])" and found that it works as it should. Nice, I know have a much better understanding.

Comment: I still don't understand why chained find.find does not work - I'll save that for further study. I also looked into using filter, but realize it is not meant for this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be 
`form_args = $("#actions").find("[name!='cc'][name!='ee']").serialize();`

Find the element attribute name!=cc AND name!=dd

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct. The find clause needs to be written as you show - no comma in between and no space, either (I tried it with a space). Very finicky. I need to find a good tutorial about constructing these filters.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is incorrect try this:

```
form_args = $("#actions").find("[name!='cc'],[name!='ee']").serialize();
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9TH8y/)

You need to find `cc` and `ee` from `#actions` so use comma to separate them in the attrubute selector.

Why your code was not working was because you are trying to find `bb` in `#actions` fine, but then you are trying to find `cc` in `bb` which is not a child of `bb`. so you get nothing. Using comma separator in the selector you are trying to find `cc` as well as `bb` which are descendant of `#actions`

Comment: You show an excerpt from my jsfiddle (thanks for looking!, my original text here was wrong). I see that your suggestion is correct. Your explanation of my mistake (not child of bb) makes sense according to my original (mistaken), code block, but as shown now ([name!='bb']). shouldn't the chain work?

Comment: @GlennN ahh i got what you are saying try this form_args = $("#actions").find("input:not([name='cc'],[name='ee'])").serialize(); http://jsfiddle.net/HZEL3/

Comment: Thanks, I independently came up with that and found it works. Should have read your new comment first. Basically these selectors are set union or intersection and we can use boolean equivalence to turn intersection selector into a union selector.